# Underscore.js record handling capacity

Tags: underscore.js

I loved the underscore.js library. I am now trying to use the library on 25Million records. Will it be possible without any performance lag. Also what is the record handling capacity of underscore.js without any performance lag.

Please guide me as i am new to underscore.js.

Thank You

Comment: Why don't you run some benchmarks yourself and see the results? You can start with 1 million records and increase it during the way

Comment: That is a cool idea. I was just trying to figure out that whether underscore.js is better than crossfilter.js with such huge data.

Comment: 25 million records would probably be better off inside a database of some kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked Underscore Test suite [here](http://underscorejs.org/test/).

Comment: I checked now. Cool stuff